# How to fix LaravelExcel UTF-8 Characters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I want to download data from view with LaravelExcel. Here is my Export Class:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Member\Student;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class StudentExportView implements FromView
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('admin.students.custom', [
           'students' => Student::take(1)->get(),
           'customs' => Student::take(1)->get(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is the Controller Method for downloading `csv`:

```
public function export_view()
    {
        return Excel::download(new StudentExportView, 'studentlist.csv');
    }
```

And here is the route that calls this method:

`Route::get('export_view','StudentAdminController@export_view')->name('students.export_view');`

But the problem is, the content that gets downloaded goes like this:

[image]

As you can see the headings are broken and body seems to be empty.

So how to solve this issue?

---

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="thead-dark">
            <th>Row</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Family Name</th>
            <th>National Code</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Province</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Degree</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Registered Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if($students->count() != 0)
        @foreach($students as $student)
            <tr data-id="{{ $student->mbr_id }}"
                data-mobile="{{ $student->mbr_mobile }}"
                data-post-code="{{ $student->mbr_post_code }}"
                data-address="{{ $student->mbr_address }}"
            >
                <td>{{ $student->mbr_name }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ $student->mbr_family }}
                    <a class="information text-danger float-left"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $student->mbr_national_code }}</td>
                <td>{{ $student->mbr_mobile }}</td>
                <td>{{ $student->province }}</td>
                <td>{{ $student->city }}</td>
                <td>{{ $student->degree }}</td>
                <td>{{ $student->grade }}</td>
                <td>
                @if($customs->find($student->mbr_id))
                    {{ jdate($customs->find($student->mbr_id)->created_at) }}
                @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" style="text-align: center">No data for showing
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to publish the excel config by using this command :-

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

then , in config/excel.php , find and change this key :

```
'use_bom' => false, to be 'use_bom' => true,
```

this solve the problem for me.

Comment: That was great man, thank u. But the body content are still empty. How to fix this

Comment: can you show view file to us , update the question with uploading the view file and pict for the excel body ?

Comment: Sure, I'm adding it

Comment: I just added my view codes to the question. Plz check it out

Comment: add : <meta charset="UTF-8"> in the head of the page , then run composer dump-autoload